# How to create a list of sequentially numbered folders using an existing folder name as the base name

Tags: bash, directory, mkdir

I've done a small amount of bash scripting.  Mostly modifying a script to my needs.
On this one I am stumped.
I need a script that will read a sub-folder name inside a folder and make a numbered list of folders based on that sub-folder name.

Example:
I make a folder named “Pictures”.
Then inside I make a sub-folder named “picture-set”
I want a script to see the existing sub-folder name (picture-set) and make 10 more folders with sequential numbers appended to the end of the folder names.
ex:
folder is:  Pictures
sub-folder is: picture-set

want to create:
“picture-set-01”
“picture-set-02”
“picture-set-03”
and so forth up to 10.  Or a number specified in the script.

The folder structure would look like this:

/home/Pictures/picture-set

/home/Pictures/picture-set-01

/home/Pictures/picture-set-02

/home/Pictures/picture-set-03
... and so on

I am unable to tell the script how to find the base folder name to make additional folders.
ie: “picture-set”

or a better option:
Would be to create a folder and then create a set of numbered sub-folders based on the parent folder name.
ex:
/home/Songs  -  would become:

```
/home/Songs/Songs-001

/home/Songs/Songs-002

/home/Songs/Songs-003
```

and so on.

Please pardon my bad formatting... this is my first time asking a question on a forum such as this.  Any links or pointers as to proper formatting is welcome.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a parameter expansion you can use to generate folder names as arguments to the `mkdir` command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Creates all directories up to 10
mkdir -p -- /home/Songs/Songs-{001..010}
```

This method is not very flexible if you need to dinamically change the range of numbers to generate using variables.

So you may use a Bash `for` loop and print format the names with desired number of digits and create each directory in the loop:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

start_index=1
end_index=10
for ((i=start_index; i<=end_index; i++)); do
  # format a dirpath with the 3-digits index
  printf -v dirpath '/home/Songs/Songs-%03d' $i
  mkdir -p -- "$dirpath"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# Prerequisite:
mkdir Pictures
cd Pictures

# Your script:
min=1
max=12
name="$(basename "$(realpath .)")"
for num in $(seq -w $min $max); do mkdir "$name-$num"; done

# Result
ls
Pictures-01  Pictures-03  Pictures-05  Pictures-07  Pictures-09  Pictures-11
Pictures-02  Pictures-04  Pictures-06  Pictures-08  Pictures-10  Pictures-12
```

Comment: `seq` is not very portable, neither is `realpath` and `basename` is better replaced by POSIX `${variable##*/}`. Anyway if using `seq` you could do `seq --format="picture-set-%03g" $min $max | xargs -I{} mkdir -p -- {}`

Comment: Wow, this worked perfect!  Thank you very much for the help.